# How to use the dart:html library to write files?

Tags: dart, dart-html

Can someone please tell me how to create a file and make it available for download via browser button?

I have read about FileWriter but not found any proper example how to use it

and I found a post [How to use the dart:html library to write html files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291979/how-to-use-the-darthtml-library-to-write-html-files)

but the answer just refers to [html5lib](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html5lib) which just answers how to parse a String to HTML but not how to save as a file.

help appreciated. Am I missing something or there is no example for that usecase??

Comment: What kind of file do you want to create? (image, text, ...)

Comment: some references:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310657, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485182,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196593

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I use a combination of [Blob](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/Blob), [Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob) And [AnchorElement](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/AnchorElement) (with [download](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/AnchorElement.download) and [href](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/AnchorElement.href) properties) to create a downloadable file.

Very simple example:

```dart
// Assuming your HTML has an empty anchor with ID 'myLink'
var link = querySelector('a#myLink') as AnchorElement;
var myData = [ "Line 1\n", "Line 2\n", "Line 3\n"];
// Plain text type, 'native' line endings
var blob = new Blob(myData, 'text/plain', 'native');
link.download = "file-name-to-save.txt";
link.href = Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob).toString();
link.text = "Download Now!";
```

Comment: Created a blog post with a little more detail, but ultimately same information. http://blog.butlermatt.me/?p=130

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by [Günter Zöchbauer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334096/how-to-use-the-darthtml-library-to-write-files#comment33942198_22334096), an alternative to using `Blob`s is to base64-encode the data and generate a data URL yourself (at least for file sizes that are well within [the data URL limits of most browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695151/)).  For example:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

Uint8List generateFileContents() { ... }

void main() {
  var bytes = generateFileContents();
  (querySelector('#download-link') as AnchorElement)
    ..text = 'Download File'
    ..href = UriData.fromBytes(bytes).toString()
    ..download = 'filename';
}
```

Also note that if you do want to use a `Blob` and want to write binary data from a `Uint8List`, you are expected to use `Blob([bytes], ...)` and *not* `Blob(bytes, ...)`.  For example:

```dart
  var bytes = generateFileContents();
  var blob = Blob([bytes], 'application/octet-stream');
  (querySelector('#download-link') as AnchorElement)
    ..text = 'Download File'
    ..href = Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob)
    ..download = 'filename';
```